# Adding items into my hash table in C

Tags: c, hashtable

I am trying to add an item into my Hashtable, I have used a lot of 
printf's to see what's happening but it looks like it's supposed to add it, but it's really not.

So here's my code:

```
struct hashnode_s {
    char *key;
    ValueType tag;
    union
    {
        int IntegerValue;
        char *StringValue;
    }u;
    struct hashnode_s *next;
};
```

I am trying to imitate the GCC Compiler.
with my hash table

```
typedef struct hashtbl {
    hash_size size;
    struct hashnode_s **nodes;
    hash_size (*hashfunc)(const char *);
} HASHTBL;
```

and my insert method

```
int hashtbl_InsertString(HASHTBL *hashtbl, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    struct hashnode_s *node;
    hash_size hash;

    hash = SearchForHashIndex(hashtbl, key, value);
    if(hash ==-1)
    {
        hash=hashtbl->hashfunc(key);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "hashtbl_insert() key=%s, hash=%d\n\n\n", key, hash);

    node=hashtbl->nodes[hash];
    while(node)
    {   
        printf("In while\n\n\n\n\n");   
        /* This Code isn't correct 
        if(!strcmp(node->key, key)) {
            node->data=data;
            return 0;
        }*/
        node=node->next;
    }

    if(!(node=malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_s)))) return -1;
    if(!(node->key=mystrdup(key))) {
        free(node);
        return -1;
    }
    node->key = key;
    node->tag = StringConst;
    node->u.StringValue = value;

    node->next=hashtbl->nodes[hash];    

    printf("ADDING HASH NODE \n\n\n");

    hashtbl->nodes[hash]=node;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep on getting null values on my search for method. Which shouldn't be the case.  Am I inserting it correctly?

```
int SearchForHashIndex(HASHTBL *hashtbl, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    printf("INSIDE SEARCH FOR HASH INDEX \n\n\n\n\n");
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < CurrentHashSize; i++)
    {   
        struct hashnode_s *node;    
        node = hashtbl->nodes[i];
        printf("%d\n",i);
        if(node == NULL)
        {
            printf("NULL");
        }
        while(node)
        {
            if(strcmp(node->key,key) || strcmp(node->u.StringValue,value))
            {
                printf("INSIDE HERE!\n");
                return i;
                printf("returning %d\n",i);
            }
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
    printf("returning -1\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: First off, your `printf("returning %d\n", i)` will never evaluate, since it's after the `return` statement.

Comment: yeah i noticed. that was something i had in there i forgot to remove lol

Comment: Code is formatted by indenting it four spaces (there is a button for it too), not by using <pre> tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not look right:

```
if(!(node->key=mystrdup(key))) {
    free(node);
    return -1;
}
node->key = key;
```

You are setting `node->key` to (apparently) a copy of the provided `key`; then you immediately overwrite that pointer with the function argument, which is unlikely to be right.

Comment: im trying to get past just adding myu first node. haha i can't even get that. once i get that, then i can add more nodes onto the next so that part is ignored

Comment: @Kevin: It appears to me that this code would be executed for the first node.

Comment: @Kevin - The part @caf is referring to isn't the commented out part. `node->key = key` overwrites the previous `node->key` value, which was memory you allocated with `mystrdup`. You're throwing away the memory you allocated (which is a leak) and replacing it with whatever parameter the user passed to the function.

Comment: IM RETARDED!! I kept on recreating my table every time i find a specific #define narrative!!! I FORGOT TO RESET MY BOOLEAN!!

Answer (score 1):

strcmp() returns 0 when a successful comparison is made.  You need to change your if() condition in the search function.

Furthermore, this block in the insert routine:

```
node=hashtbl->nodes[hash];
while(node)
{   
    printf("In while\n\n\n\n\n");   
    /* This Code isn't correct 
    if(!strcmp(node->key, key)) {
        node->data=data;
        return 0;
    }*/
    node=node->next;

}
```

is useless, since you just assign newly allocated memory to node directly afterwards.

Comment: I think that block is meant for when the OP can get the "adding nodes" part to work, to check if the node is already added, and will probably return upon doing so before allocating a new node when completed.

Answer (score 0):

If your hash function is reliable (and it has to be to be a hash function), your search function shouldn't have to iterate over all the linked lists. You shouldn't need that outer `for` loop - just set `i` to `hashtabl->hashfunc(key)` and search that list for the element. If it's not in that list, it shouldn't be in any list, and if it is then you're insertion function is definitely wrong.

In fact, your search function should return either `hashtabl->hashfunc(key)` or -1.

Additionally, what should happen if someone uses the same key for different objects?

Comment: This is the first time i'm messing with hash tables. I'm still struggling haha. trying to understand, and I normally don't program in C. I'm more of a wpf/c#